# Remove action from Hybris CMS component using Impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm currently experimenting with Hybris in preparation for a project and I have some trouble making Impex do what I want to do.

The example electronics store defines the CMS actions for the ProductAddToCartComponent

```
INSERT_UPDATE ProductAddToCartComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;actions(&actionRef);&componentRef
;;AddToCart;Product Add To Cart;AddToCartAction,PickUpInStoreAction,ShareOnSocialNetworkAction;AddToCart
```

My goal is to remove the ShareOnSocialNetworkAction from the AddToCart element.
I've tried several variations of REMOVE, which mostly resulted in the AddToCart element itself being deleted, as well as INSERT_UPDATE with only the actions I wanted to retain, which didn't have any effect at all.

How can I remove only the ShareOnSocialNetworkAction from the AddToCart component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried INSERT_UPDATE with replace mode with adding all the actions but the one you want to remove ? :

```
UPDATE ProductAddToCartComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];actions(uid,$contentCV)[mode = replace];
                                       ;;AddToCart;AddToCartAction,PickUpInStoreAction;
```

Or using remove mode this way :

```
UPDATE ProductAddToCartComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];actions(uid,$contentCV)[mode = remove];
                                ;;AddToCart;ShareOnSocialNetworkAction;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the remove/replace mode. Tried the remove mode and it worked as required.